# Resizing Images in Magento

Tags: magento

I have an image that is called like:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('position','2')
```

That is the 2nd image (sort by).

Need to be able to use Magento's resize() on this, any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but try

```
$_image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('position','2');

echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(30, 30);
```

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php

```
public function init(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $attributeName, $imageFile=null)
```

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/264272/#t356324

Comment: It's not set as a thumbnail or anything else, will it still work?